# chrome devtools extension navigate to custom panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a chrome devtools extension that has both a specific panel and a sidebar pane on the "elements" panel.
I wanted to put a button in the sidebar that, once pressed, will navigate the devtools to my panel.
Creating the button is not a problem, but how do I navigate to a different panel within devtools?

I couldn't find any useful information on the documentation or elsewhere online.

Comment: Extensions can't do that, there's no such API.

Comment: Well, that's sad...
Let's hope they add it in the future then!